# Android activity startActivity on two parallel activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B which are parallel to each other. A can switch to B any time and vice versa. I don't want A or B recreated every time one calls startActivity on the other. The only way to achieve that, so far I have found, is setting A to "singleTask" and B to "singleInstance", but it seems like a giant hack to me because somewhere I read that singleTask and singleInstance should not be present in the same application. Could anyone enlighten me with the proper way to have two activities start each other without creating new instances of either activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start both Activities using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(contexts, AorB.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: With following path: A -> B -> A -> B, it only works with B -> A , but not the other way around(A->B). When I say it works, it doesn't call the onCreate method of the activity.

Comment: You have to do the same with B.

Comment: I did the same thing for B but that didn't change anything. With this intent, when B -> A, wouldn't B clear the activity stack, including itself?

Comment: hmm... did you try `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)` ?

Comment: That worked with launchMode: singleTop. Awesome, thanks so much! Please edit your answer so I could accept it as correct.